# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'icalendar' google Cloud

Tags: python, flask, calendar

[image][image]
I'm getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'icalendar' " after running google app deploy on Gcloud, I have installed the icalendar module using pip but to my surprise i'm getting an error when I try to deploy the app. I have spent hours on this your help will be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official documentation :

[Specifying Dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/specifying-dependencies)

> Dependencies for Python applications are declared in a standard
> **requirements.txt**

For example:

```
Flask==0.10.1
icalendar
```

Therefore I created a `requirements.txt` and included `icalendar` module. Then I deploy to App Engine `gcloud app deploy` and everything worked as expected.

You can follow this tutorial for better understanding the concept:

[Quickstart for Python 3 in the App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart)

Comment: Getting this error now "File "/home/vmagent/app/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import lib.icalendar
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'"

Comment: I think my answer confused you. Is not a private dependency. Just add a file requirements.txt with icalendar included as my example and deploy it .It worked for me . Then your code is the same, ```from icalendar import Calendar```

Answer (score 0):

Pls. check `pip list` to see if that has been installed properly. If yes, pls. check that import statement in the python terminal.

If that works, then use `which python` and ensure that it is the same virtual environment where you are installing and running from.

Comment: if I check pip list it's appearing on the list of packages and if I import it on the terminal it's not giving any errors

Comment: which python is giving me this directory /usr/local/bin/python

Comment: when I import icalendar on this path that I got from which python /usr/local/bin/python there are no errors at all

Comment: check the ```which python``` where it was giving error ? Is the same where there are no errors ?